# IOS Method Calling

Tags: ios, methods, nsstring

I have a method which i need to call within another method. in a UIViewController

```
//This is how i call methoed
tmpUITextView.text= [self ssidValue:1 arrayOf:ssidArray];


//my Method 
+ (NSString *)ssidValue:(NSInteger)selectedValue arrayOf:(NSMutableArray *)tmpArray {

    NSString *result=[tmpArray objectAtIndex:selectedValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
    return result;
}
```

but i am getting waring ( warning: 'UIViewController' may not respond to '-ssidValue:arrayOf:')and crash it.

Please tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are declaring the method as a *class method* (note the "+") but you are calling it as an *instance method*.

To solve this, either declare it as an instance method (replace "+" with "-") or call it as a class method:

```
[[self class] ssidValue:1 arrayOf:ssidArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

use the instance method type declaration i.e.,. use "-" instead of "+" for method declaration
and you can call it using the class name

```
   tmpUITextView.text= [class_Name ssidValue:1 arrayOf:ssidArray];
```

class_name is the name of the class Wherethe method initialized

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the method as a class method (note the "+") but you are calling it as an instance method.

To solve this, either declare it as an instance method (replace "+" with "-") or call it as a class method:

```
[[self class] ssidValue:1 arrayOf:ssidArray];
```